Media Groups в aiogram
есть код выдает ошибку
суть кода чтобы пользователь отправлял сгруппированные фото в бот и бот отправлял все эти фото тоже сгруппировано в канал, но выдается ошибка (aiogram 3.x)
if message.photo:
        media_group = MediaGroupBuilder(caption="Media group caption")
        photo_ids = [photo.file_id for photo in message.photo]
        for phot in photo_ids:
            media_group.add_photo(media=phot)
        await bot.send_media_group(user_channel, media=media_group)

  await message.answer('Нажмите когда хотите завершить', reply_markup=keyboard2)


"но выдается ошибка" - догадаться самостоятельно или дополните вопрос?
